# a proof for dense subsets in metric spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $A \subset X$. If $\partial A=X$ then prove that $A$ is dense in $X$. 
And i also need an example for the converse is not always true.

Comment: Do you know the definitions of *dense* and $\partial A$?

Comment: @Karolis Juodelė i know them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\partial{A} = X $ then $ X =\partial{A}\subseteq \bar{A} \subseteq X \Rightarrow X =\bar{A}  $ and then $A$ is dense by definition.

For the counterexample we can consider $ A =D(0,1) \cup \{\mathbb{Q\times Q}\}$ in $\mathbb{R^{2}}$, where $D(0,1)$ is a disc; we have that $A$ is dense but $\partial{A} \neq \mathbb{R^{2}}$.

Comment: $A = \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\} \subset \mathbb{R}$ is dense and open, so $\partial{A} = \mathbb{R}\setminus A = \{0\}$. Somewhat simpler, maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:Try to prove that $$d(x,clA)=0$$  for all $x\in X$

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $\partial A\subseteq\overline A.$ For a counterexample to the converse, obtain $A$ by removing a single (limit) point from one of the more familiar metric spaces.